# Is it safe to share a NEAR protocol function access key publicly if only limited to intended functions?

Tags: nearprotocol

Given I want to let someone without a NEAR account call a specific function in a smart contract, and to do so I create a function access key for my own account with permissions limited to that specific contract and function.

Will I then risk anything else than the allowance (0.25N) granted to that function access key?

Is it a bad idea to even share that access key publicly, let's say if I want to include that access key in a link?

I could of course also create an implicit account and then a function access key from that, but is it really necessary from a security point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is the basis for what's known as a linkdrop. You can learn more about how those work [here](https://github.com/keypom/keypom#how-linkdrops-work).

To answer your question, it depends on what that function call access key can do. If it can call a method `withdraw` that can withdraw $NEAR from your contract account with no limits, then it's probably not a good idea to share it publicly.

If you're confident that the key cannot be used in a malicious way to steal assets or do things that are unwanted, then there is no risk in sharing it publicly.

I would also stress that the 0.25 $NEAR allowance is NOT saying "this key can be used to withdraw up to 0.25 $NEAR on my account". That allowance is for transactions fees ONLY (Gas). 0.25 $NEAR equates to roughly 2.5 PetaGas (2500 TGas) which is a lot of computation power and can be used to call a method many times. What happens in that method, however, has nothing to do with the allowance.

You can spend 0.01 $NEAR worth of allowance (100 TGas) and call a method which withdraws 1000 $NEAR from the contract account. The allowance is ONLY for computation.

TLDR: it depends on what the key can do and allowance != net outbound NEAR from a contract account.